# NPE in PrimeFaces validator attribute method

Tags: java, primefaces, selectonemenu

I try to validate a `p:selectOneMenu` using the validator attribute, but in the validate method the value of object is null. I don´t understand why it is null, somebody could help me. I´m using PrimeFaces 6.2.

My xhtml is:

```html
<p:selectOneMenu id="somFieldType"
                 widgetVar="somFieldType"
                 converter="entityConverter"
                 required="false"
                 value="#{paramDetail.article_field_type}"
                 validator="#{detailArticleBean2.isTypeValid}"
                 ... >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{i18n['avocado.general.seleccionar']}" itemValue="0"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{i18n['avocado.general.texto']}" itemValue="1"/>
    ...
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

In my bean I´m only printing the value:

```java
public void isTypeValid(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    System.out.println(value.toString());
}
```

The console returns an error:

```
javax.el.ELException: /Ref/Art/artDetail.xhtml @165,67 validator="#{detailArticleBean2.isTypeValid}": java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
```

I´d appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value is `null`, so you cannot apply `.toString()`. Use something like:

```java
public void isTypeValid(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (value == null) {
        // Value is unset; don't validate
        return;
    }
    // Value is set; do validation
    ...
}
```

See also:

- [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)